# Javascript VAR syntax

Tags: javascript

What does this mean in var definition:

```
var array = array || [];
```

... and next two parts of javascript are equal each other?

```
var array = array || [];
array.push([1],[2]);
array.push([3]);
```

=

```
var array = array.push([1],[2],[3]) || [];
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that if array is a falsy value (`undefined`, `null` etc.) - the value that will be assigned to the `var array` is  an empty array - `[]`;

EDIT:

the second part of your question - no these are not equivalent.

For instance, when array is `undefined`:

```
var array = array.push([1],[2],[3]) || [];
```

this will throw an exception.

This:

```
var array = array || [];
array.push([1],[2]);
array.push([3]);
```

will not.

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent to this,

```
var array;
if(array){
  array = array;
} else {
  array = [];
}
```

Just in a much shorter form.

In the second part, No those two are not equivalent.

```
array.push([1],[2],[3])
```

needs to be executed no matter what, if you use `|| []` it will not be added.

In other words, you start with this,

```
var array;
if(array){
  array = array;
} else {
  array = [];
}
array.push([1],[2],[3]);
```

And you then modified it to this,

```
var array;
if(array){
  array = array;
  array.push([1],[2],[3]);
} else {
  array = [];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm already resolve this. Im just trying to optimize Google Analytics tracking code.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement will set `array` to an empty array if it is a falsey value (`null`, `undefined`, etc.).

The next two parts are not equal, and will likely fail when you try to call `push` on something that is not known to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

It's setting the var to a new array if it's not defined.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax uses the javascript boolean `or` operator, and its evaluation of truthy/falsey statements to provide a valid default value.

So

```
var array = array || [];
```

Means "use an empty array if `array` evaluates false".